# How to find out more details on CsvHelper.TypeConversion.CsvTypeConverterException?

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I am trying to import CSV files with the following code:

```cs
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
\\\ ...
try
  {
     var csv = new CsvReader(csvReader, new CsvConfiguration { 
        HasHeaderRecord = false, Delimiter = ";" });
     records = csv.GetRecords<FileDataContainerDisplay>().ToList();
   }
catch (Exception)
   {
      throw new FileFormatException();
}
```

The code fails with

> Exception thrown: 'CsvHelper.TypeConversion.CsvTypeConverterException' in CsvHelper.dll

The curious thing is that the code used to work with files of the following kind:

```
Date;CurveName;Gridpoint;Timebase;Value
1.1.1900 00:00:00;A;1;1;0.12
1.1.1900 00:00:00;A;1;2;0.23
1.1.1900 00:00:00;A;1;3;0.34
...
```

**May anybody guide me where to find more details on which type conversion failed exactly?**

By the way, the definition of `FileFormatException` is rather boring:

```cs
public class FileFormatException : Exception
{ }
```

#### References

- [Merging CSV files with different headers using CSVhelper C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43831267/merging-csv-files-with-different-headers-using-csvhelper-c-sharp)

Comment: actually i'd build my own csv parser, csv is so primitive that you can handle it all on your own in 50 lines or less. no need for another dependency here... to fix your exception: just use string properties in FileDataContainerDisplay and parse the datatypes on your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is your configuration doesn't match your file. Your configuration says there is no header record, but your file appears to have a header record, so it is trying to read the word "Date" as a `DateTime`. When I look at the inner exception, I get more information.

```
The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.
```

You should include the innerException with your `FileFormatException` class.

```cs
public class FileFormatException : Exception
{
    public FileFormatException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException)
    {
    }
}

catch (Exception e)
{
   throw new FileFormatException("Error message", e);
}
```